# Using TRANSPOSE in an IF statement and Lookup Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use the result of a TRANSFORM inside an IF statement where if the value returned in transform is blank, the value_if_true should look up the value of the previous cell, add one to it and show that, otherwise just show the result of the transform.

My issue is that the formula inside value_if_true, returns #VALUE even though on evaluation it is calculating the right value to return but if I replace it with a static text it works fine.

Below is what I'm trying to do:

```
{=IF(TRANSPOSE(Master!A7:A110)="",INDIRECT("RC[-1]",0)+1,TRANSPOSE(Master!A7:A110))}
```

This is what works:

```
{=IF(TRANSPOSE(Master!A7:A110)="","blah",TRANSPOSE(Master!A7:A110))}
```

Thank You!

Comment: TRANSPOSE may not be the best option here. Can you show mocked up or redacted data together with expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for responding so late, surprisingly using named ranges instead of explicitly calling them out has solved the problem. To explain:

This is my data in the 'Reference' sheet. It is merely week numbers expressed in descending YYYYWW format:

```
201701
201702
201703
201704
201705
201706
201707
201708
```

The size of this list changes as data for more weeks flows in, the maximum items it can have is 104 weeks (two years rolling data). I've selected the entire 104 row range say `$A$1:$A$104` that this list can expand to occupy and named it `ListOfWeeks`

On my display sheet I have selected the full 104 column range that these dates will be transposed into say `$I$6:$DH$6` then entered the following formula into the formula bar:

```
=IF(TRANSPOSE(ListOfWeeks)=0,"",TRANSPOSE(ListOfWeeks))
```

followed by a `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` and it is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the value in RC[-1] is a number? If it is text and can't be converted to a number, then it will return #Value

Also, are you entering this array formula into a single cell and then filling it, or are you array-entering it into an entire range at once? If you're array-entering it into the entire range at once, then also be aware that RC[-1] will always refer to the cell that is to the left of the top-left cell of the output-array range.